How to forecast a variable using exogenous data with statsmodel's SARIMAX?
I have a function that takes in 3 time-series dataframes: train_data, test_data, and exog_train.
For each dataframe, indicies use date-time dates. Each dataframe only has 1 column.
order and seasonal_order are
def Evaluate_Model(train_data, test_data, exog_train, order=(1,0,0), seasonal_order=(0,0,1,4)):

    # Training Phase
    model = SARIMAX(train_data, exog=exog_train, order=order, seasonal_order=seasonal_order,
                    enforce_stationarity=False, enforce_invertibility=False)
    fitted_model = model.fit(disp=False)
    
    # Testing Phase
    forecast = fitted_model.forecast(steps=len(test_data))  # Forecast endogenous variable only

    # Calculate evaluation metrics
    mae = mean_absolute_error(test_data, forecast)
    rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(test_data, forecast))
    mape = np.mean(np.abs((test_data - forecast) / test_data)) * 100
    mase = np.mean(np.abs(test_data - forecast)) / np.mean(np.abs(test_data.diff().dropna()))
    
    return mae, rmse, mape, mase, forecast

I would like to be able to train the model using train_data and exog_train, and then evaluate the model's ability to forecast the test_data. However, I run into the following error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [103], line 1
----> 1 mae, rmse, mape, mase, forecast = Evaluate_Model(detrend_SO2_df_train, detrend_SO2_df_test, PC1, order, seasonal_order)

Cell In [101], line 180
    177 fitted_model = model.fit(disp=False)
    179 # Testing Phase
--> 180 forecast = fitted_model.forecast(steps=len(test_data))  # Forecast endogenous variable only
    182 # Calculate evaluation metrics
    183 mae = mean_absolute_error(test_data, forecast)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/base/wrapper.py:113, in make_wrapper.<locals>.wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    111     obj = data.wrap_output(func(results, *args, **kwargs), how[0], how[1:])
    112 elif how:
--> 113     obj = data.wrap_output(func(results, *args, **kwargs), how)
    114 return obj

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/mlemodel.py:3442, in MLEResults.forecast(self, steps, **kwargs)
   3440 else:
   3441     end = steps
-> 3442 return self.predict(start=self.nobs, end=end, **kwargs)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/mlemodel.py:3403, in MLEResults.predict(self, start, end, dynamic, **kwargs)
   3357 """
...
   1771                          ' `exog` argument.')
   1772     exog = np.array(exog)
   1773     required_exog_shape = (out_of_sample, self.k_exog)

ValueError: Out-of-sample operations in a model with a regression component require additional exogenous values via the `exog` argument.

I have attempted to incorporate the exogenous data into the code like so:
However, the model necessitates that the "exog=" parameter in fitted_model.forecast to be of the same size as the test data. This doesn't make sense to me because in forecasting a real-life scenario, it is impossible to obtain future exogenous data. What if I had future exogenous data? How would it be used by the model?
def Evaluate_Model(train_data, test_data, exog_train, order=(1,0,0), seasonal_order=(0,0,1,4)):

    # Training Phase
    model = SARIMAX(train_data, exog=exog_train, order=order, seasonal_order=seasonal_order,
                    enforce_stationarity=False, enforce_invertibility=False)
    fitted_model = model.fit(disp=False)
    
    # Testing Phase
    forecast = fitted_model.forecast(steps=len(test_data), exog=exog_train)  # Forecast endogenous variable only

    # Calculate evaluation metrics
    mae = mean_absolute_error(test_data, forecast)
    rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(test_data, forecast))
    mape = np.mean(np.abs((test_data - forecast) / test_data)) * 100
    mase = np.mean(np.abs(test_data - forecast)) / np.mean(np.abs(test_data.diff().dropna()))
    
    return mae, rmse, mape, mase, forecast

